# Does Android 8.1(Oreo) lack "Landscape Orientation" mode?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, auto-rotation, aosp

I am using AospExtended v5.7 for [tomato](https://downloads.aospextended.com/tomato) and I have noticed something weird. The rotation button in the status bar only toggles between *Portrait Mode* and *Auto Rotate Mode*. It lacks the *Landscape Mode*(even when I try to do it whilst holding the phone in Landscape).

Is it normal? I feel its weird because I had this functionality in LineageOS 14.1(basically Nougat), but its not in a later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal. Even my phone has the same. I can be on either 
"Auto Rotate" or "Portrait Only".

You can reply on 3rd party apps like "Rotation Control" to force a landscape if needed.